# How to flip bar chart horizontally in Tableau?

Tags: bar-chart, visualization, distribution, tableau-desktop

I have made a bar chart using the count of genders & age groups of a dataset. It came as a normal bar chart.

But, I want to flip the chart horizontally. Simply, I want the Y Column on the Right side of the chart, not on the Left side (The traditional way).

N.B.: I don't want to swap the axis i.e. interchanging x and y axis.

I have created this: [Created chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Geocc.png)

But, I want to create like this:
[Desired chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWrrD.png)

Answer (score 0):

A very easy thing to try is to edit the axis (by right clicking on the axis and choosing edit, or by just double clicking on the axis. Then you can check the reverse axis option and see if that satisfies you.

The axis will be reversed as you requested but the labels will still be on the left.

Putting the bar labels on the right requires more effort. One way is to make a separate chart that just lists the labels and then combine both on a dashboard